# The mapDispatchToProps not dispatching the actionCreators to the required component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to use mapDispatchToProps to get the action all action creators in Something Component but it seems whatever going in the props of Something component is  undefined I don't know why.... I have checked my actioncreators and other files but they seems to be correct I am pretty sure about it

I have tried everything I could here but there might be something small I might be missing and I am pretty sure it's in this code I am providing for sure

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDishes, fetchPromos, fetchComments, fetchLeaders } from './redux/ActionCreators';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchDishes: () => dispatch(fetchDishes()),
  fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
  fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),
});


 const store = ConfigureStore();

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <Something />
    </Provider>
  );
}

class Something extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDishes();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchPromos();
    this.props.fetchLeaders();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {

  }
}


connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Something);

export default App;
```

I guess I should also share my actionCreators here....

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

export const fetchComments = () => (dispatch) => {
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments')
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response;
    }
    else {
      var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
    var errMess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errMess;
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(comments => dispatch(addCommnets(comments)))
  .catch(error => dispatch(commentsFailed(error.message)))
}


export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(dishesLoading());
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'dishes')
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response;
    }
    else {
      var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
    var errMess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errMess;
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(dishes => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
  .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)))
}


export const fetchPromos = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(promosLoading());
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'promotions')
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response;
    }
    else {
      var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
    var errMess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errMess;
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(promos => dispatch(addPromos(promos)))
  .catch(error => dispatch(promosFailed(error.message)))
}


export const fetchLeaders = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(leadersLoading());
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'leaders')
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response;
    }
    else {
      var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
    var errMess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errMess;
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(leaders => dispatch(addleaders(leaders)))
  .catch(error => dispatch(leadersFailed(error.message)))
}

export const leadersLoading = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.LEADERS_LOADING
});

export const leadersFailed = (errmess) => ({
  type:ActionTypes.LEADERS_FAILED,
  payload: errmess
})
```

Only a part of actionCreators are uploaded which I thought might be necessary

All the fetch functions must be passed and nothing should be come as undefined in Something component.

Comment: Added actionCreators to the code now everything must be easy to analyse...I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a connected component but not using it.

Here it is with the imports and exports:

```
// Something.js

// A couple of imports...

class Something extends Component {
  // ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchDishes: () => dispatch(fetchDishes()),
  fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
  fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)
```

```
# App.js

// A couple of imports ...
import Something from './Something'

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <Something />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Note: Since you don't have ay props from `mapStateToProps`, you can simply put `null` as first argument.

Comment: Getting another error now it says....
You must pass a component to the function returned by connect instead received undefined.

Comment: It seems the connect function is returning undefined object.... I don't know why????

Comment: It's Something that is undefined. You must be importing it incorrectly

Comment: Importing what incorrectly???? The connect or the actionCreators... can you suggest me something more??? Thanks for help.... @Matthieu

Comment: If u r talking about Something component then it's not importing it's made there....

Comment: I edited the answer to also specify the imports and exports, you should be good

Comment: Thanks a lot bro I moved the Something component to some other file and imported it from there after connecting it and so the whole thing worked out....Finally 
You are a lifesaver bro. @Matthieu
One more thing don't ya think the import might look for a .js file Something to take import from there in this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component is using your `Something` component directly, and not its connected version.

```
...

const ConnectedSomething = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(Something);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedSomething />
    </Provider>
  );
}

...
```